# I need help getting python 3

Tags: pi-3

How do I get python 3 on the programming section on the main menu. I have tried watching multiple videos but I can not find anything that works

Comment: Do not use text terminal. GUI Desktop > programming > IDLE python.  Start with Hello World.  Show us your code which does not work.

Comment: Why do you want ‘Python 3’ on the programming menu? I generally use Thonny to write my Python code. You can run your code within Thonny or from a terminal window eg ‘python3 test.py’.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "Python 3 on the programming menu". Do you mean a specific IDE, like IDLE, or just any? The latest Raspbian image from raspberrypi.org/downloads includes Thonny (a Python 3 editor) instead of IDLE. You can also install Mu (another Python 3 editor) `sudo apt install mu-editor` or IDLE `sudo apt install idle3`. Installing any of those will put it in the main menu.

Comment: Watching the videos won't install Python for sure. Trying out commands suggested in the videos (and reporting errors you encounter in your question) may eventually work.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion here is that most Raspberry Pi Python tutorial videos were made before IDLE was removed from the default Raspbian image (in favor of Thonny, a recent development).

Thus, comments suggesting to try out commands in the videos are not helpful. If you wish to follow those videos starting from the point of opening **Python 3 (IDLE)**, as @ben_nuttall suggested you can first get set up with:

```
sudo apt install -y idle3
```